# JPA - subtract two date column

Tags: oracle, jpa, eclipselink, ejb-3.0, jpql

I have project using EJB3 + JPA(eclipselink) + Oracle database + glass-fish
everything work fine i can get any table from database

what I want is to execute this sql statement using JPQL

```
select  de - sysdate as newde
from deinfo;
```

I try this code

```
 factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
 EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
 // Read the existing entries and write to console

String qSelect = "SELECT d.de - CURRENT_Date as newde  FROM Deinfo d   ";

Query q = em.createQuery(qSelect);
```

but it's throw the error when create query

```
An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT d.de - CURRENT_Date as newde  FROM Deinfo d ]. 
[7, 19] The left expression is not an arithmetic expression.
```

why I can't subtract tow date using JPQL but I can use the same sql above inside Oracle sql command and work fine

I also try

```
select  CURRENT_Date  as newde
```

it's return the current date so no problem with command 
it's just I can't use mathematics operation on date using JPQL

Comment: tow? cloumns? Is it too much effort to fix typos even in the title of your request for help?

Comment: is that help you to find solution? anyway thanks i fix it

Comment: no problem thanks anyway